# Mixed data types in data fields

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am authoring a code designed to detect index and report errors found within very large data sets. I am reading in the data set (`csv`) using `pandas`, creating a `dataframe` with dozens of columns. Numerical errors are easy by converting the column of interest to an `np` array and using basic logical expression and the `np.where` function. Bam!

One of the errors I am looking for is an

> invalid data type

For example, if the column was supposed to be an array of floats but a string was inadvertently entered smack dab in the middle of all of the floats. When converting to a `np` array it THEN converts all values into strings and causes the logic expressions to fail (as would be expected).

Ideally all non-numeric entries for that data column would be indexed as

> invalid data type

with the values logged. It would then replace the value with `NaN`, convert the array of strings to the originally intended float values, and then continue with the assessment of numerical error checks.

This could be simply solved through for loops with a few try/catch statements. But being new to python. I am hoping for a more elegant solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please review [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Add an example

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [great expectatoins](https://great-expectations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) which aims to solve a similar problem. Note that until they implement their [`expect_column_values_to_be_parseable_as_type`](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/issues/110), you can force you column to be a string and use regex for the checks instead. For example, say you had a column called `'AGE'` and wanted to validate it as an integer between 18 and 120

```
import great_expectations as ge

gf = ge.read_csv("my_datacsv",
                 dtype={
                     'AGE':str,
                 })

result = gf.expect_column_values_to_match_regex('AGE',
                                                r'1[8-9]|[2-9][0-9]',
                                                result_format={'result_format': 'COMPLETE'})
```

Alternatively, using `numpy` maybe something like this:

```
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def is_num(num):
    try:
        float(num)
        return True
    except:
        return False

A = np.array([1,2,34,'e',5])
is_num(A)
```

which returns

```
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True])
```